# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i}<2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

My task is to show: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i} < 2$$
There is also a hint: try to bound this sum term by term with
a geometric progression.
I have tried following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i} = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^i} - 1 = \frac{1 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} - 1 = 1 - (\frac{1}{2})^n $$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
But I'm not sure if I am thinking about it the right way. I can't progress from this point further. Problem looks quite simple and basic, but I don't know 'the smart trick' there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transforming this seems to be the way to go.  Note
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i} =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac{1}{2^i}\right)$$

As each term, $\frac{1}{2^i}$ is added $i$ times. Now, using the formula for the sum of geometric progressions, we have $$\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac{1}{2^i}=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}-\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$

So the sum becomes $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac{1}{2^i}\right)<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}=2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}<2
$$

Comment: Why not just compute the sum: by the use of your method, the exact value is $2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}$, clearly less then $2$

Comment: @larry01 Because the question does not ask to compute the sum but to show it is $<2$.

Comment: @larry01 By the way, since you are here, what happens [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2168890/)? Are you leaving the page in disarray (although specific suggestions were made to transform it into a decent question)? What for?

Comment: @larry07 That is unnecessary.

Comment: Pretty clear, thank you! I think second line is something I didn't see.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n x^i=x\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}<\frac x{1-x}=g(x)$$ for $x$ in $(0,1)$.

Then by differentiation, noting that $f(0)=g(0)=0$, the requested sum verifies

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac i{2^i}=\left.x\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1}\right|_{x=1/2}=\frac12f'\left(\frac12\right)<\left.xg'(x)\right|_{x=1/2}=\frac12\frac1{\left(1-\dfrac12\right)^2}=2.$$

Comment: Tricky one, but understandable, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$S:=\frac01+\frac12+\frac24+\frac38+\cdots\frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac n{2^n}=\\
\frac12\left(\frac{0+1}1+\frac{1+1}2+\frac{2+1}4+\cdots\frac{n-2+1}{2^{n-2}}+\frac {n-1+1}{2^{n-1}}\right).$$

Then

$$2S-S=\frac11+\frac12+\frac14+\cdots\frac1{2^{n-2}}+\frac1{2^{n-1}}-\frac n{2^n}<2.$$

---

This result makes is difficult to avoid computing the sum as a by-product,

$$S=2-\frac1{2^{n-1}}-\frac n{2^n}.$$

Comment: Uhmm, sorry I don't see how you made it to step 2 and 3...

Comment: @PhotonLight: check term for term.